# XtraReport - get data from non-master datasource based on a parameter value

Tags: devexpress, parameter-passing, datasource, xtrareport

I want to get data from non-master datasource based on a parameter value.

Let's say we have 2 datasources in report:
* datasource1 - main dataprovider
* datasource2 - from which I need to get additional data

And also we have a report parameter, which is bound to the datasource2 to populate dropdown when report is opened.

I need that whenever user picks one of the option from parameter dropdown and submits, to grab corresponding item data from datasource2 and put in the report.

Is it possible? I didn't find any answer on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be possible if you leave single datasource but with two tables/datamembers,
for example DevExpress SqlDataSource may have number of [Queries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2554/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Providing-Data-to-Reports/Tutorials-and-Code-Examples/Bind-a-Report-to-a-Database),
in the needed label you may write the [expression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/120091/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Using-Expressions)

> iif(Parameters.UseDefault, OptionalTable.DefaultValue, DataTable.ValueColumn)

is this helpful for your scenario?

Comment: I am not using SQLdatasource and can't use. I am using object datasource directly (I'm not sure if it's correct naming for it but hope you understood) and hence it's not fix for me, but thanks for the response

Comment: so you may create an aggregated object datasource with two list-properties - first with your main data and the second one with additional data. unfortunately, there is no solution out of the box